# controller not reaching magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, controllers, store-view, page

One strange thing is happing in my application, I have one custom link in my email. On development server everything works fine, but on production server when I clicked the link nothing happens,

Blank page, I tried to die inside controller,  but my looks like my page is not reaching the controller .

Does anyone face this before

Comment: can you post error log

Comment: I dnt see any error , thats the issue, blank page

Comment: Are you trying to debug in production or development mode?

Comment: production mode